# syntax invalid while translating C code to Python

Tags: python, c

I have C snippet(decompiled from IDA) to be translated to Python:

```
  # v29 = 0;
  # v30 = -1342924972;
  # while ( v29 < v62 ) // v62 is length of string to be decoded
  # {
  #   v31 = (int *)v60;
  #   v32 = __ROL4__(v30, 3);
  #   v33 = *((_BYTE *)v31 + v29) - v29 - v32;
  #   v34 = (int *)v60;
  #   *((_BYTE *)v34 + v29) = v33;
  #   v35 = __ROR4__(v33, 11);
  #   v36 = __ROL4__(v30, 5);
  #   v30 = v30 + (v29++ ^ v36 ^ v35) - 1204489519;
  # }


def decode_msg(dstr, str_len):
  bstr = list(dstr)
  v29 = 0
  v32 = 0
  v33=0
  v35=0
  v30 = -1342924972
  while(v29 < str_len):
    v32 = ((v30 & 0xffffffff) << 3) & 0xffffffff
    v33 = ((hex(ord(bstr[v29])) & 0xff) - v32) & 0xff
    bstr[v29] = v33 & 0xff
    v35 = ((v33 & 0xffffffff) >> 11) & 0xffffffff
    v36 = ((v30 & 0xffffffff) << 5) & 0xffffffff
    v29 = v29 + 1
    v30 = (v30 & 0xffffffff) + (v29 ^ v36 ^ v35) - 1204489519
  return ''.join(bstr)
```

C code is in comments. The C code decodes a byte array, v60 is the array. I have error:

```
v33 = ((hex(ord(bstr[v29])) & 0xff) - v32) & 0xff
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I am totally Python noob. I think `hex()` converts each item in `dstr` to a number. So why is it still `str`?

Comment: No, hex() converts a number to a string containing the hexadecimal representation of that number.

Comment: from IDA to Python: nice touch! you just don't have to use `hex`, `ord` is already a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, `hex` returns a string, which obviously does not support bitwise operations like `&` with a numeric type:

```
>>> type(hex(3))
<class 'str'>
>>> hex(3) & 0xf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

The `ord` function already returns an int, so you can just remove the `hex` function altogether:

```
>>> ord('c') & 0xff
99
```

Answer (score 2):

`ord` is already an int, you don't need the `hex`, which returns a string.

And I may be wrong, but this line may give you problems

```
bstr[v29] = v33 & 0xff
```

You'd need to cast it to string again:

```
bstr[v29] = chr(v33 & 0xff)
```