# decoding ransom note(from C to Python)

Tags: python, c

further question after [syntax invalid while translating C code to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892551/syntax-invalid-while-translating-c-code-to-python/)

I have encoded ransom note from Locky(the `pkt2` below). And I have decompiled C code to decode the ransom note(in comments). I tried to translate the C code to Python. Below is what I have:

```
  # v29 = 0;
  # v30 = -1342924972;
  # while ( v29 < v62 )
  # {
  #   v31 = (int *)v60;
  #   v32 = __ROL4__(v30, 3);
  #   v33 = *((_BYTE *)v31 + v29) - v29 - v32;
  #   v34 = (int *)v60;
  #   *((_BYTE *)v34 + v29) = v33;
  #   v35 = __ROR4__(v33, 11);
  #   v36 = __ROL4__(v30, 5);
  #   v30 = v30 + (v29++ ^ v36 ^ v35) - 1204489519;
  # }


def decode_msg(dstr, str_len):
  bstr = list(dstr)
  v29 = 0
  v32 = 0
  v33 = 0
  v35 = 0
  v30 = 0xAFF49754
  while(v29 < str_len):
    v32 = ((v30 & 0xffffffff) << 3) & 0xffffffff
    v33 = ((ord(bstr[v29]) & 0xff) - v29 - v32) & 0xff
    bstr[v29] = chr(v33 & 0xff)
    v35 = ((v33 & 0xffffffff) >> 11) & 0xffffffff
    v36 = ((v30 & 0xffffffff) << 5) & 0xffffffff
    v29 = v29 + 1
    v30 = (v30 & 0xffffffff) + (v29 ^ v36 ^ v35) - 1204489519
  return ''.join(bstr)

print decode_msg(str(pkt2), len(str(pkt2)))
```

Run above code I couldn't get meaningful result. The result should be mostly English text. So where is wrong? The Python code doesn't match the C code?

The `pkt2` is:

```
pkt2 = bytearray([
0x48, 0x54,
0x54, 0x50, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x20, 0x32,
0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x4f, 0x4b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x53,
0x65, 0x72, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x6e,
0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x78, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x61,
0x74, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x54, 0x68, 0x75, 0x2c,
0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x20, 0x46, 0x65, 0x62, 0x20,
0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x36, 0x20, 0x30, 0x33, 0x3a,
0x30, 0x34, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x38, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4d,
0x54, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65,
0x6e, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x54, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x3a,
0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x2f, 0x68, 0x74,
0x6d, 0x6c, 0x3b, 0x20, 0x63, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72,
0x73, 0x65, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x55, 0x54, 0x46, 0x2d,
0x38, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65,
0x6e, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4c, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x74,
0x68, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x31, 0x30, 0x38, 0x39, 0x0d,
0x0a, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74,
0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x6b, 0x65, 0x65,
0x70, 0x2d, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x0d,
0x0a, 0x56, 0x61, 0x72, 0x79, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x41,
0x63, 0x63, 0x65, 0x70, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x45, 0x6e,
0x63, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x0d, 0x0a,
0x0d, 0x0a, 0xb1, 0x8a, 0x5d, 0x46, 0xb3, 0x6f,
0x9c, 0xf9, 0x50, 0x02, 0x3b, 0x04, 0x7b, 0x60,
0xf7, 0x50, 0x39, 0x5d, 0x97, 0xc5, 0x13, 0xe2,
0x81, 0xe1, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x48, 0x2f, 0x45,
0xb4, 0x5f, 0xf1, 0x86, 0xa2, 0x6b, 0xdd, 0x06,
0x9e, 0x3c, 0x1e, 0xb0, 0xcc, 0x2e, 0x32, 0x9b,
0xf3, 0xf0, 0x92, 0x06, 0x6d, 0x2c, 0x65, 0xe6,
0x2d, 0x65, 0x61, 0xd4, 0xeb, 0x37, 0x6d, 0xd6,
0xcb, 0xe7, 0xfd, 0x1f, 0x8a, 0xa9, 0x3e, 0x79,
0x83, 0x90, 0x8f, 0xa4, 0xf9, 0x89, 0x97, 0x6a,
0x89, 0x51, 0x71, 0x1f, 0x40, 0x63, 0x60, 0xc7,
0x1a, 0x1b, 0xef, 0x5a, 0xfb, 0xb4, 0x12, 0xd1,
0x2b, 0xa9, 0x17, 0xd1, 0x88, 0xb8, 0x66, 0x05,
0xe9, 0x81, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xa0, 0xfd, 0x8c, 0x11,
0x7c, 0xe6, 0x2e, 0x43, 0xdf, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x2c,
0xc8, 0x56, 0x4f, 0x50, 0xf9, 0xfb, 0xf1, 0xf3,
0x92, 0x80, 0x84, 0x59, 0x3e, 0x6a, 0x33, 0x8d,
0x8f, 0x85, 0xaf, 0x02, 0x4b, 0x36, 0xa9, 0xc1,
0x1f, 0x23, 0x20, 0x18, 0x84, 0xd0, 0x9d, 0x9c,
0xa2, 0x07, 0x0d, 0x97, 0x0d, 0x5d, 0xc7, 0x40,
0x48, 0xc8, 0x61, 0xd5, 0x6c, 0x0a, 0xb7, 0xc4,
0x53, 0xb3, 0x12, 0x05, 0x37, 0x8e, 0x87, 0x7c,
0xb9, 0xc5, 0x2e, 0xc1, 0x01, 0x36, 0xe5, 0x58,
0x38, 0xed, 0x16, 0xe5, 0xbe, 0x75, 0xcd, 0xa4,
0x3b, 0xa4, 0xd7, 0x41, 0xde, 0xf0, 0x68, 0xaa,
0x51, 0x96, 0xa6, 0xe3, 0x8c, 0x7b, 0x38, 0x20,
0xb1, 0x18, 0x10, 0xbe, 0x63, 0x88, 0xa4, 0x65,
0x2b, 0xa7, 0x6a, 0x9c, 0x0d, 0xab, 0x6c, 0xab,
0x8f, 0x3b, 0x18, 0xee, 0xd8, 0xc6, 0xc1, 0xee,
0xcc, 0xb1, 0x76, 0xe5, 0x39, 0xdc, 0x69, 0x33,
0x85, 0xfa, 0x07, 0x72, 0xcc, 0xdb, 0x4d, 0x38,
0x8b, 0x1c, 0xa8, 0x58, 0x22, 0xf0, 0x5c, 0xa5,
0x56, 0xa6, 0x4c, 0xc6, 0xef, 0xb8, 0x06, 0xa4,
0xd3, 0x0a, 0xda, 0x47, 0xd6, 0x89, 0xd1, 0x25,
0xf2, 0xa3, 0xbc, 0xa9, 0xd4, 0x06, 0x12, 0x73,
0x63, 0x3a, 0x2d, 0xbb, 0x49, 0xb9, 0xfc, 0x04,
0x1b, 0xb9, 0xb2, 0xb9, 0xf8, 0x0e, 0xde, 0xcd,
0xed, 0x71, 0x53, 0xb7, 0xda, 0x69, 0xf5, 0xf2,
0xfb, 0xda, 0xa7, 0x52, 0xb0, 0xd6, 0x20, 0xd5,
0xff, 0x1d, 0x05, 0x4d, 0xa3, 0xc6, 0x4a, 0x7c,
0x51, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x1b, 0xd8, 0x65, 0x0a, 0xc8,
0x00, 0xdf, 0xf0, 0x17, 0x51, 0xe4, 0xc9, 0x5b,
0x61, 0x2a, 0x3b, 0x22, 0xaa, 0x0a, 0xf3, 0x5e,
0xce, 0xdd, 0x0f, 0x4d, 0x20, 0x00, 0xf4, 0x5a,
0x83, 0xb4, 0xa9, 0x2a, 0x4a, 0xfd, 0x1d, 0xf9,
0xe5, 0x9f, 0x1a, 0x0e, 0xee, 0x34, 0x36, 0x37,
0xf2, 0x92, 0x57, 0x79, 0x80, 0xcb, 0x02, 0x4a,
0xbb, 0xfb, 0xf0, 0x8d, 0xda, 0xe4, 0x88, 0xd0,
0x57, 0x47, 0x33, 0xff, 0x30, 0x7d, 0x7d, 0x65,
0x2d, 0x3e, 0xfc, 0x6d, 0xf0, 0x78, 0x0f, 0x15,
0x68, 0xe2, 0x70, 0x59, 0x1a, 0xeb, 0x45, 0x7a,
0xab, 0x86, 0xc8, 0x9c, 0x15, 0xf7, 0x9b, 0x10,
0x87, 0x3a, 0xf2, 0x76, 0x5c, 0x98, 0x00, 0x95,
0xa8, 0xcc, 0xa9, 0x58, 0x0a, 0xd4, 0x5e, 0xac,
0x47, 0xb4, 0x9a, 0x46, 0xb8, 0xf8, 0x45, 0x0b,
0xae, 0x23, 0xb5, 0xf4, 0x00, 0xb4, 0x83, 0x0d,
0xde, 0x4a, 0x98, 0x1c, 0x43, 0xe5, 0x2c, 0xbb,
0x82, 0x0d, 0xc4, 0x27, 0x7d, 0xf9, 0x2d, 0x90,
0x9b, 0xdd, 0x8b, 0x51, 0x7b, 0xf0, 0xbb, 0xd6,
0x39, 0x94, 0x80, 0x58, 0x00, 0x3b, 0xe8, 0x6c,
0x32, 0xf1, 0x98, 0x91, 0xb2, 0x95, 0x39, 0x51,
0x81, 0x59, 0x54, 0xfe, 0x23, 0x71, 0x8f, 0x9f,
0xcf, 0x6c, 0xf2, 0x64, 0x39, 0xa4, 0xe4, 0xd6,
0x8c, 0x3a, 0x27, 0x83, 0x9a, 0xcc, 0xe3, 0x77,
0x31, 0x13, 0xd4, 0x85, 0xae, 0x47, 0xcc, 0x5b,
0x4b, 0x6f, 0xf4, 0x2b, 0xc9, 0xff, 0x71, 0x09,
0x1d, 0x1d, 0xb6, 0x51, 0xf3, 0x39, 0x80, 0x38,
0x8c, 0xee, 0x5c, 0xa2, 0xcf, 0x56, 0x1d, 0xcd,
0x51, 0x5e, 0x87, 0xd7, 0x21, 0x8d, 0x5b, 0xc6,
0x20, 0x4c, 0xaf, 0xdf, 0x83, 0xfe, 0x8c, 0xac,
0xa7, 0xa5, 0x66, 0x45, 0x97, 0xc1, 0x5a, 0x6b,
0x13, 0xba, 0xaf, 0x11, 0x5e, 0xcc, 0x01, 0x90,
0x6d, 0x97, 0x11, 0xdb, 0xf3, 0x88, 0xcb, 0x20,
0x81, 0xd4, 0x05, 0x18, 0x69, 0xfa, 0x3c, 0x3b,
0xde, 0xd5, 0x11, 0xef, 0x17, 0xa2, 0xe6, 0xd6,
0x6a, 0x99, 0x11, 0x44, 0xd1, 0xd4, 0x5a, 0xff,
0x30, 0x85, 0x9d, 0xf1, 0xcc, 0xb3, 0xd3, 0x99,
0xa6, 0x05, 0x64, 0x1c, 0x46, 0xb4, 0xe5, 0x64,
0xb7, 0x9d, 0x8a, 0xf4, 0xcf, 0x33, 0xb4, 0x86,
0x6b, 0x3c, 0xac, 0x0a, 0x80, 0x30, 0xcf, 0xff,
0x0d, 0x2b, 0x08, 0x3c, 0x08, 0xdc, 0xc3, 0xec,
0x0b, 0xea, 0xcc, 0xa0, 0xdc, 0x70, 0x09, 0xf7,
0xd0, 0x3a, 0x50, 0xfb, 0xb3, 0xef, 0x22, 0x33,
0xf9, 0xf1, 0x67, 0x0f, 0x1a, 0xba, 0x50, 0xd6,
0x62, 0xa6, 0x15, 0x3a, 0x4a, 0x50, 0x81, 0xc5,
0x90, 0xd3, 0x9d, 0x8e, 0x9b, 0xc0, 0xb5, 0xf4,
0x65, 0x33, 0xbd, 0xad, 0x3c, 0x4f, 0xf1, 0xc5,
0x35, 0x73, 0x48, 0xe1, 0xb2, 0xb2, 0x40, 0x58,
0xec, 0xbe, 0xab, 0x12, 0xf5, 0x5b, 0x34, 0x3e,
0x3d, 0x07, 0x41, 0xe4, 0xdf, 0x9a, 0x44, 0x37,
0x9f, 0xc1, 0xc0, 0x2f, 0xad, 0x8f, 0x8e, 0xfe,
0xbd, 0x17, 0x66, 0x46, 0x32, 0x93, 0xe5, 0x47,
0x8c, 0xef, 0x88, 0xc1, 0x8b, 0x49, 0xd0, 0x90,
0xc0, 0x5a, 0x5d, 0x1e, 0x70, 0x2f, 0xbd, 0xd9,
0x69, 0xb7, 0x14, 0x1d, 0x99, 0x1e, 0xb5, 0xf7,
0xff, 0x81, 0x5f, 0x35, 0x85, 0xf9, 0xa3, 0x14,
0xf0, 0xdd, 0xa3, 0x3b, 0x61, 0xdd, 0x3d, 0x4d,
0x18, 0x21, 0xc5, 0xe5, 0x95, 0xee, 0x40, 0x3d,
0x44, 0x03, 0x5c, 0xc0, 0xa6, 0xfc, 0x50, 0xc1,
0x96, 0x2f, 0x90, 0xf2, 0x15, 0x77, 0x3a, 0x09,
0x9a, 0x7d, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xdd, 0xea, 0x4c, 0x3d,
0x02, 0xce, 0x99, 0x27, 0xef, 0xf0, 0xeb, 0x25,
0x5a, 0x9b, 0x9a, 0xf2, 0xc3, 0x8f, 0x97, 0xfa,
0x06, 0x64, 0x0f, 0x1e, 0x66, 0x35, 0x41, 0x13,
0xdd, 0xb8, 0xcc, 0x08, 0x87, 0xfc, 0x1c, 0xf5,
0x07, 0xe1, 0x30, 0x6b, 0xac, 0x03, 0x81, 0x49,
0x65, 0xd0, 0x02, 0x97, 0xc2, 0x06, 0xcc, 0xa9,
0x9a, 0xb2, 0x7a, 0x04, 0xab, 0x87, 0xda, 0x03,
0xd3, 0x78, 0x5b, 0xc6, 0x49, 0x70, 0x10, 0x37,
0x81, 0xc2, 0xa0, 0x0f, 0x6a, 0x84, 0xc0, 0x10,
0x78, 0x89, 0xf8, 0x76, 0x64, 0xa1, 0xb5, 0xf5,
0x7b, 0x5d, 0xeb, 0x1b, 0x5d, 0xd6, 0xca, 0x58,
0x66, 0x23, 0x48, 0x15, 0x1a, 0x22, 0x60, 0x42,
0xe0, 0x7e, 0x6f, 0x98, 0x36, 0xe7, 0x69, 0x43,
0x19, 0x39, 0x42, 0x96, 0x3d, 0xaa, 0xb3, 0x67,
0xff, 0x50, 0x17, 0x9b, 0x9e, 0x06, 0x93, 0x42,
0x92, 0xd7, 0xc3, 0xb0, 0x3f, 0xb8, 0xd5, 0xde,
0xfa, 0xef, 0xc9, 0xde, 0x13, 0x5b, 0x66, 0x50,
0xf3, 0x60, 0x8f, 0x14, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x2c, 0x15,
0x79, 0x70, 0x85, 0xdb, 0x20, 0xa5, 0x53, 0xb1,
0x5e, 0x9d, 0xd7, 0xdf, 0x4d, 0x80, 0x9a, 0xfa,
0x00, 0xdf, 0xf3, 0x09, 0x61, 0xae, 0xdd, 0xc0,
0x4f, 0x90, 0xfa, 0x31, 0x83, 0x30, 0x86, 0x71,
0x34, 0x97, 0xeb, 0x69, 0xca, 0x29, 0xaf, 0xce,
0x91, 0x61, 0xc3, 0x11, 0xd0, 0x97, 0x27, 0x54,
0xc5, 0x5e, 0x23, 0xe3, 0x02, 0x2f, 0xe7, 0x44,
0xb3, 0x8d, 0x11, 0x89, 0x4b, 0xee, 0x4d, 0xbf,
0x7d, 0xe1, 0xa6, 0x49, 0x17, 0x59, 0x65, 0xb3,
0xc5, 0xb0, 0x55, 0x71, 0x6e, 0xa7, 0xe0, 0x3a,
0x06, 0xdc, 0xd7, 0xf6, 0x54, 0x49, 0x9e, 0x7c,
0x6f, 0xe4, 0x1a, 0xca, 0xe8, 0x25, 0x35, 0x21,
0xb3, 0x87, 0x67, 0x58, 0x5c, 0xd7, 0x31, 0xa5,
0xdb, 0x34, 0x23, 0x60, 0x9f, 0x80, 0xb1, 0x42,
0x77, 0x5f, 0x0d, 0xaf, 0x2b, 0x99, 0xd0, 0x4c,
0xb8, 0xb9, 0xbc, 0x5b, 0x15, 0x84, 0xab, 0x7f,
0x0d, 0xfe, 0x14, 0x74, 0x29, 0x45, 0x61, 0x31,
0x33, 0x31, 0x8e
])
```

Comment: Try converting each byte to an ASCII character

Comment: To start with, `v32 = ((v30 & 0xffffffff) << 3) & 0xffffffff` is not `ROL` It's `SHL`

Comment: @robyschek thx dude. If you answer this question, I would give you credits.

Answer (score 0):

`bytearray` holds raw bytes, so you need to do `pkt2.decode()` to decode them as *utf-8* (this is the default, although you could specify the encoding yourself), which gives you a `str`.

In short, just replace `str(pkt2)` with `pkt2.decode()`.

Comment: It doesn't work... ERROR: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 180: invalid start byte`. `str(pkt2)` is changed to `pkt2.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @JACKM, this means that `pkt2` uses an other encoding.